# window.opener undefined inside same domain redirection

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have been trying to set a parent form's value from a popup window through `window.opener`. However, `window.opener` is undefined upon execution.

Main window:

```
showmodaldialog("popup.aspx", null, window styles with width and height);
```

Pop-up:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("#hidvalue").value = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `window.opener` when `showModalDialog` is involved. But what you *can* do is pass window as a `dialogArgument`:

Main window:

```
showModalDialog("popup.aspx", window, 'window styles with width and height');
```

Pop-up:

```
var opener = window.dialogArguments;
opener.document.getElementById("#hidvalue").value = "hello";
```